Django automatic conversion/casting when doing lookups
Could someone explain to me where I can find information about why this works in Django? I did some research in the official documentation and couldn't find anything.
from django.db import models

class Document(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

# Query using an integer
document1 = Document.objects.get(id=1)

# Query using a string that can be converted to an integer
document2 = Document.objects.get(id='1')

# Both queries should yield the same result

I check this pages in the official documentation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/fields/#model-field-types
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/db/queries/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/lookups/


This is because of the  .get_prep_value(…) [Django-doc] and .get_db_prep_value(…) methods [Django-doc] of the IntegerField [GitHub]:

def get_prep_value(self, value):
    value = super().get_prep_value(value)
    if value is None:
        return None
    try:
        return int(value)
    except (TypeError, ValueError) as e:
        raise e.__class__(
            "Field '%s' expected a number but got %r." % (self.name, value),
        ) from e


def get_db_prep_value(self, value, connection, prepared=False):
    value = super().get_db_prep_value(value, connection, prepared)
    return connection.ops.adapt_integerfield_value(
        value, self.get_internal_type()
    )

This determines what value to pass to the database, it thus checks for the connection, which encapsulates the dialect-specifics of the database, how to talk to the database.
For more information, see the converting query values to database values section [Django-doc].
Without too much self promotion, I wrote an article [django-antipatterns] that uses this technique to make a field that automatically truncates values to an hour, week, or month, to make querying more convenient.
